# how to transform a JSON coming from an API into DATAFRAME pyspark?

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to read the Json returned by an API and play it to a DATAFRAME pyspar, but the file comes out in just one field named _corrupt_record:

my JSON is something like this:

```json
{
  "title": "texto",
  "nickname": "(app)",
  "language": "en",
  "folder_id": "0",
  "category": "",
  "question_count": 3,
  "page_count": 3,
  "response_count": 2636,
  "date_created": "2021-01-27T19:22:00",
  "date_modified": "2021-06-01T11:43:00",
  "id": "00000",
  "buttons_text": {
    "next_button": "next",
    "prev_button": "prev",
    "done_button": "done",
    "exit_button": ""
  },
  "is_owner": true,
  "footer": false,
  "custom_variables": {
    
  },
  "href": "https://api",
  "analyze_url": "https://api",
  "edit_url": "https://api",
  "collect_url": "https://api",
  "summary_url": "https://api",
  "preview": "https://api",
  "pages": [
    {
      "title": "",
      "description": "",
      "position": 1,
      "question_count": 1,
      "id": "00000",
      "href": "https://api",
      "questions": [
        {
          "id": "602406071",
          "position": 1,
          "visible": true,
          "family": "matrix",
          "subtype": "rating",
          "layout": null,
          "sorting": null,
          "required": {
            "text": "texto",
            "type": "all",
            "amount": "0"
          },
          "validation": null,
          "forced_ranking": false,
          "headings": [
            {
              "heading": "texto"
            }
          ],
          "href": "https://api",
          "answers": {
            "rows": [
              {
                "position": 1,
                "visible": true,
                "text": "",
                "id": "00000"
              }
            ],
            "choices": [
              {
                "position": 1,
                "visible": true,
                "text": "texto",
                "id": "00000",
                "is_na": false,
                "weight": 0,
                "description": ""
              },
              {
                "position": 2,
                "visible": true,
                "text": "texto",
                "id": "00000",
                "is_na": false,
                "weight": 0,
                "description": ""
              },
              {
                "position": 3,
                "visible": true,
                "text": "texto",
                "id": "00000",
                "is_na": false,
                "weight": 0,
                "description": ""
              },
              {
                "position": 4,
                "visible": true,
                "text": "texto",
                "id": "00000",
                "is_na": false,
                "weight": 0,
                "description": ""
              },
              {
                "position": 5,
                "visible": true,
                "text": "texto",
                "id": "00000",
                "is_na": false,
                "weight": 0,
                "description": ""
              }
            ]
          },
          "display_options": {
            "show_display_number": true,
            "display_type": "emoji",
            "display_subtype": "star",
            "left_label_id": null,
            "left_label": "",
            "right_label_id": null,
            "right_label": "",
            "middle_label_id": null,
            "middle_label": "",
            "custom_options": {
              "color": "#f5a623",
              "option_set": [
                
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I need it to be separated by columns, including the aligned fields, I want to separate by columns:

I'm trying it:

```py
endpoint = f"my_API"
headers = {'Authorization': subscription_key}
request = requests.get(endpoint, headers=headers)
aall_df = json.loads(request.content)
rdd = sc.parallelize([aall_df])
df1 = spark.read.json(rdd)
df1.show(truncate=False)
```

Expected output:

| title | nickname | language | folder_id | category | question_count | page_count | date_created | date_modified | id | next_button | prev_button | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| texto | (app) | en | 0 | nan | 3 | 3 | 2021-01-27... | 2021-01-27... | 0 | next | prev | ... |

Can someone help me, please?

Comment: It would help for you to provide the expected output

Comment: expected output:
title | nickname | language| folder_id | category | question_count | page_count | date_created | date_modified | id | next_button| prev_button|...
texto |(app)     | en      | 0         |          | 3              | 3          |2021-01-27... |2021-01-27...  |0000|next        |prev        |...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the string/unparsed json to the rdd instead of the parsed json

```py
aall_df = request.content # json.loads(request.content) 
rdd = sc.parallelize([aall_df])
df1 = spark.read.json(rdd)
df1.show(truncate = False)
```

prints:

```
+-----------+--------------------+--------+-----------+-------------------+-------------------+-----------+---------+------+-----------+-----+--------+--------+--------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-----+
|analyze_url|buttons_text        |category|collect_url|date_created       |date_modified      |edit_url   |folder_id|footer|href       |id   |is_owner|language|nickname|page_count|pages                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    |preview    |question_count|response_count|summary_url|title|
+-----------+--------------------+--------+-----------+-------------------+-------------------+-----------+---------+------+-----------+-----+--------+--------+--------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-----+
|https://api|{done, , next, prev}|        |https://api|2021-01-27T19:22:00|2021-06-01T11:43:00|https://api|0        |false |https://api|00000|true    |en      |(app)   |3         |[{, https://api, 00000, 1, 1, [{{[{, 00000, false, 1, texto, true, 0}, {, 00000, false, 2, texto, true, 0}, {, 00000, false, 3, texto, true, 0}, {, 00000, false, 4, texto, true, 0}, {, 00000, false, 5, texto, true, 0}], [{00000, 1, , true}]}, {{#f5a623, []}, star, emoji, , null, , null, , null, true}, matrix, false, [{texto}], https://api, 602406071, null, 1, {0, texto, all}, null, rating, null, true}], }]|https://api|3             |2636          |https://api|texto|
+-----------+--------------------+--------+-----------+-------------------+-------------------+-----------+---------+------+-----------+-----+--------+--------+--------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-----+
```

and

```py
df1.printSchema()
```

prints

```
root
 |-- analyze_url: string (nullable = true)
 |-- buttons_text: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- done_button: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- exit_button: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- next_button: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- prev_button: string (nullable = true)
 |-- category: string (nullable = true)
 |-- collect_url: string (nullable = true)
 |-- date_created: string (nullable = true)
 |-- date_modified: string (nullable = true)
 |-- edit_url: string (nullable = true)
 |-- folder_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- footer: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- href: string (nullable = true)
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- is_owner: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- language: string (nullable = true)
 |-- nickname: string (nullable = true)
 |-- page_count: long (nullable = true)
 |-- pages: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- description: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- href: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- position: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- question_count: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- questions: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- answers: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- choices: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- description: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- is_na: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- position: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- text: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- visible: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- weight: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- rows: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- position: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- text: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- visible: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- display_options: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- custom_options: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- color: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- option_set: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- display_subtype: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- display_type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- left_label: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- left_label_id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- middle_label: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- middle_label_id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- right_label: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- right_label_id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- show_display_number: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- family: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- forced_ranking: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- headings: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- heading: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- href: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- layout: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- position: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- required: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- amount: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- text: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- sorting: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- subtype: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- validation: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- visible: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- title: string (nullable = true)
 |-- preview: string (nullable = true)
 |-- question_count: long (nullable = true)
 |-- response_count: long (nullable = true)
 |-- summary_url: string (nullable = true)
 |-- title: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: your solution worked, but when I use explode to access all items linearly, it's duplicating, can you help me?
Example:
explodedDF = df1.withColumn("column1",explode('pages'))            
explodedDF = explodedDF.withColumn("column2",explode_outer('column1.questions'))            
explodedDF = explodedDF.withColumn("column3",explode_outer('column2.answers.choices'))
explodedDF = explodedDF.withColumn("column4",explode_outer('column2.answers.rows'))

Comment: @CarlosEduardoBilarRodrigues That's how explode works see [example here](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-explode-nested-array-into-rows/)